# Not enough memory while using the Tokenizer in keras.preprocessing.text

Tags: python, nlp, keras, classification, recurrent-neural-network

I want to build a RNN model using keras to classify sentences.

I tried the following code:

```
docs = []
with open('all_dga.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        dga_domain, _ = line.split(' ')
        docs.append(dga_domain)

t = Tokenizer()
t.fit_on_texts(docs)
encoded_docs = t.texts_to_matrix(docs, mode='count')
print(encoded_docs)
```

but got a MemoryError. It seemed that I couldn't load all data into the memory. This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    encoded_docs = t.texts_to_matrix(docs, mode='count')
  File "/home/yurzho/anaconda3/envs/deepdga/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/text.py", line 273, in texts_to_matrix
    return self.sequences_to_matrix(sequences, mode=mode)
  File "/home/yurzho/anaconda3/envs/deepdga/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/text.py", line 303, in sequences_to_matrix
    x = np.zeros((len(sequences), num_words))
MemoryError
```

If anyone familiar with keras, please tell me how to pre-process the dataset.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try reduce `num_words`.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you have no problem fitting the documents to create the vocabulary from `t.fit_on_texts(docs)` since the error happened on `t.texts_to_matrix(docs, mode='count')`.

So you can convert the documents in batches

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

t = Tokenizer()

with open('/Users/liling.tan/test.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:      
        t.fit_on_texts(line.split()) # Fitting the tokenizer line-by-line.

M = []

with open('/Users/liling.tan/test.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        # Converting the lines into matrix, line-by-line.
        m = t.texts_to_matrix([line], mode='count')[0]
        M.append(m)
```

But you'll see run into `MemoryError` at some point later if your computer can't handle the amount of data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an older question now, but I just ran into this issue myself. I used a combination of alvas answer above and then the keras `fit_generator()` method.

The use of a data generator and the batch method mentioned by alvas solved the memory usage issue.

Comment: Do you mind offering a working example for what you did?